# how define "for" for specified columns to avoid wasting time

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset has 54 columns.i want to define a loop ("For") to get some specified columns (20 columns) then apply a simple function . how can i do this? i want to avoid wasting time

Comment: Do you know how to write a for loop? Do you know how to call a specific column? Do you want to apply _the same_ function to all columns?

Comment: `for column in some_specified_columns: df[column].apply(simple_function)` ?

Comment: I know how to define a loop and the same function will be applied. but I dont know how to tell it to get columns one by one. i mean i want to give the list of columns then it crate new columns (applied function) accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's say we have a list with the specified 20 columns, something like `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', ...]`

Then we can do

```
specified_columns = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for column in specified_columns:
    df.['new'+column] = df[column].apply(simple_function)
```

this should create a set of 20 new columns called `new_foo`, `new_bar`, etc.

If we had another list with the names of the 20 new columns, in the same order, we could do:

```
specified_columns = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
new_columns = ['bla', 'ble', 'bli']

for i in range(len(specified_columns)):
    df.[new_columns[i]] = df[specified_columns[i]].apply(simple_function)
```

Comment: Note that in the second example you can do: for old_column, new_column in zip(specified_columns, new_columns)